# How do I test collision between two rectangles, one with multiple instances of its class?

Tags: java, logic, lwjgl

This is more of a question of logic than code, I do believe.

I have two rectangles (of class "RedBlock"), referenced by "Main.blocks[]" and another rectangle (of class "MainCharacter"), whose class this code comes from. The rectangle of class "MainCharacter" should stop moving when it collides with either of the rectangles in the "Block" array (named "blocks"). Since it is in a "for" loop, any "if" statement inside the block must be true for both instances of "Block" for it to keep the "MainCharacter' from moving. Also, since the code is run twice, the "movementSpeed" seems to be doubled, caused by the "setX()" method being called twice.

My problem, therefore, is that I cannot test collision between one of the two blocks, but only between both blocks at the same time, and that I cannot accurately control the speed of the "MainCharacter" (as it is relative to the number of blocks). Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? If you have a superior form of collision detection at hand, feel free to include that in your answer.

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= Main.blocks.length - 1; i++) {
        if (Main.blocks[i] != null) {
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
                if (Math.abs(getRight() - Main.blocks[i].getLeft()) < movementSpeed
                        && getBottom() <= Main.blocks[i].getTop()
                        && getTop() >= Main.blocks[i].getBottom()) {
                    setX(getX() + Math.abs(getRight() - Main.blocks[i].getLeft()));
                } else {
                    setX(getX() + movementSpeed);
                }
            } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
                if (Math.abs(getLeft() - Main.blocks[i].getRight()) < movementSpeed
                        && getBottom() <= Main.blocks[i].getTop()
                        && getTop() >= Main.blocks[i].getBottom()) {
                    setX(getX() - Math.abs(getLeft() - Main.blocks[i].getRight()));
                } else {
                    setX(getX() - movementSpeed);
                }
            } if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
                if (Math.abs(getBottom() - Main.blocks[i].getTop()) < movementSpeed
                        && getLeft() <= Main.blocks[i].getRight()
                        && getRight() >= Main.blocks[i].getLeft()) {
                    setY(getY() - Math.abs(getBottom() - Main.blocks[i].getTop()));
                } else {
                    setY(getY() - movementSpeed);
                }
            } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
                if (Math.abs(getTop() - Main.blocks[i].getBottom()) < movementSpeed
                        && getLeft() <= Main.blocks[i].getRight()
                        && getRight() >= Main.blocks[i].getLeft()) {
                    setY(getY() + Math.abs(getTop() - Main.blocks[i].getBottom()));
                } else {
                    setY(getY() + movementSpeed);
                }
            }
        } else return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling the event in the keyboard event? why not just check block[i].leftrighttop and down from the block[i+1] and then move it back the distance it traveled inwards eg.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Main.blocks.length - 2/*Because we will be checking i +1*/; i ++){
if((Main.blocks[i].left > Main.blocks[i+1].left)&&(Main.blocks[i].left < Main.blocks[i+1].left)){}
}
```

that would check the x pos of the blocks... now you can just tell it to move to the nearest point and do the same for the rest :) hopes it helps! i always did it in delphi7.